# Akka-http approach to handle websocket commands

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, workflow, akka-stream

Let's say I have controller that handles commands that I receive from websocket.

```
class WebSocketController(implicit M: Materializer)
  extends Controller
    with CirceSupport {

  override def route: Route = path("ws") {
    handleWebSocketMessages(wsFlow)
  }

  def wsFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
    Flow[Message].mapConcat {
      case tm: TextMessage =>
        decode[Command](tm.getStrictText) match {
          // todo pass this command to some actor or service 
          // and get response and reply back.  
          case Right(AuthorizeUser(login, password)) =>
            TextMessage(s"Authorized: $login, $password") :: Nil
          case _ =>
            Nil
        }

      case bm: BinaryMessage =>
        bm.dataStream.runWith(Sink.ignore)
        Nil
    }

}
```

So, I get a command, deserialize it and next step I want to do is to pass it to some service or actor that will return me `Future[SomeReply]`.

The question is:
What is the basic approach of handling such flow with akka streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling `Future`s inside a `Flow`, `mapAsync` is usually what you're looking for. To add to your specific example:

```
def asyncOp(msg: TextMessage): Future[SomeReply] = ???
def tailorResponse(r: SomeReply): TextMessage = ???

def wsFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
  Flow[Message]
   .mapConcat {...}
   .mapAsync(parallelism = 4)(asyncOp)
   .via(tailorResponse)
```

`mapAsyncUnordered` can also be used, in case the order of the `Future`s result is not relevant.
Parallelism indicates how many `Future`s can be run at the same time, before the stage backpressures.

See also

- stage [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#mapAsync)
- how to use in conjunction with `ask` - [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#mapAsync_+_ask)